# String to date in XSLT 2.0: error using xs:date

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have the following String in my xml:

```
<birthday>1968-05-30 23:00:00.0 UTC</birthday>
```

I need to convert this to a date (CET). So basically I want to parse this String somehow to a datetime, add 1 hour, and then retrieve the date.

But I am already failing at simply parsing this to a date:

```
xs:date(fn:substring(birthday,1,10))
```

fails with the error

> FORG0001: Invalid date "" (Too short)

But `xs:date('1968-05-30')` works fine.

I get a similiar error when trying to retrieve the time with `xs:time(fn:substring(birthday,12,8))`.

What I am doing wrong?

(Using Saxon 9)

Comment: Please post minimal but complete samples allowing us to reproduce the problem, the substring attempt to isolate an `xs:date` should work, see http://xsltransform.net/eiZQaFo. The complete string does not have the right format for an `xs:dateTime`, as that is `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss`, plus a timezone I would need to look up.

Comment: My initial suspicion would be that somehow you aren't pointing to the fn namespace, and fn:substring() is silently becoming "".  Does it work without the fn prefix?

Comment: Like Martin said, please post minimal but complete samples that still reproduce the problem. My guess is that whatever your current context is when you call `substring()` does not have a child `birthday`. You could check this by replacing "birthday" with the actual string in the `substring()` call. Example: `substring('1968-05-30 23:00:00.0 UTC',1,10)`

Comment: It's pretty clear that "birthday" hasn't selected any node. The usual reasons for that are either (a) your context is wrong (the context item isn't the parent of the birthday element), or (b) there's a default namespace in force.

Comment: I have tried excluding the following errors:  (a) Context wrong: <xsl:value-of select="fn:substring(birthday,1,10)"/>  works, so the context must be right. (And I doublechecked that the context item is the parent of birthday). (b) @Michael: what do you mean at default namespace in force?

Comment: I can't think of any explanation that accounts for all the symptoms you describe simultaneously. So please post a repro: that will end the guesswork and give us something to get our teeth into.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="xs:date(xs:dateTime(translate(substring(birthday, 1, 19), ' ', 'T')) + xs:dayTimeDuration('PT1H'))"/>
```

[demo](http://xsltransform.net/gWmuiJq)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the comments.

Problem is solved..Its rather embarrassing, but I was getting the error, because in my input XML I hadn't noticed that I had partner nodes which did NOT have a birthday (case of a company - which is modeled as a partner too). 
Thus the error was correctly saying "Invalid date "" (Too short)". It just didn't say where exactly :/

So lesson learned: before converting String to Date, verify that String is not empty and not null ;)